# trash bytes end of file compiled with g++

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

I ve been looking through the GCC source code and google with no luck at all.

I am compiling this code:

```
extern "C" int XMain(unsigned int hModule, unsigned int ulReason, unsigned int lpReserved)
{
    //if (ulReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {

    }

    return 1;
}
```

With the following commands:

> g++-4.9.2 -O0 -shared -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -nostartfiles
>   -fno-use-linker-plugin -Wl,-entry,_XMain main.cpp -o TestLib.dll

And here is the output seen with a disassembler:
[image]

The code output is ok, but what are those trash bytes at the end of the code?
What do they do ?

Comment: What does the `gcc -S` say? I don't believe there is any guarantee that compilers will only ever generate exactly the minimum bytes obviously needed by your program... It is allowed for the compiler to generate "extra stuff", without any particlar explanation. [Or it is just random garbage that the disassembler produced?]

Comment: With: g++-4.9.2 -S -O3 -fno-align-functions -shared -nodefaultlibs -nostdlib -nostartfiles -fno-use-linker-plugin -Wl,-entry,_XMain main.cpp -o TestLib.dll

Comment: .file "main.cpp"
 .text
 .globl _XMain
 .def _XMain; .scl 2; .type 32; .endef
_XMain:
 movl $1, %eax
 ret

Comment: No sign of trash bytes in the asm output as we can see.

Comment: Why is this important? Like I said, I don't think any compiler guarantees that there won't be padding or similar? Interestingly, there are two `nop` first, then 4 `0xff` and 4 `0x00` bytes - which seems like someone is trying to make sure it's "not executable" (good when you happen to accidentally modify the return address of some function by just a little bit, and return just after the end of the function, for example) [0xff, 0xff is not executable, but 0x00,0x00 is]

Comment: That's just part of the object code formatting, surely?

Comment: I tried adding some code to grow the output and interestingly the padding stays intact just farther location cause of the grow.

Comment: On my system immediately following the `ret` instruction is a new section, `eh_frame_hdr`.

Comment: This is weird, i dont have a eh_frame_hdr section after the code.

Answer (score 0):

GCC pads based on `-falign-functions`, which is on with `-O2` and `-O3`.

I don't know why it's padding with those specific bytes.

Comment: Except optimisation is given as `-O0`?